# Need help on change Progress dialog spinner color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to change the `Spinner` color in Android.

This is my code,

```
 public void showProgressDialog() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this,R.style.MaterialDialog) {
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("");
    pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.hide();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

style::

```
<style name="MaterialDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Finally my `ProgressDialog` is showing the `Spinner` in light blue color but as per my requirement I need the color to be red.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `material spinner` to easily customise your spinner

https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

Comment: Here tab_selected_text_color means red color only.

Comment: i tried above scenarios and these are not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this, R.style.ProgressBar);
```

I just change the style as below...and its working for.

```
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this style attribute to red color

**Color.xml**

```
 <color name="tab_selected_text_color">#FF0000</color>
```

**style.xml**

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent of your activity theme to red

or you can try this:

progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);